# Android ExpandableListView not changing to light text in night mode

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-theme, android-darkmode, android-night-mode

I am creating an `ExpandableListView` and its adapter (`ExpandableListAdapter`, using a `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`) by doing something like this. It works fine in light mode, but the text remains black in dark mode / night mode, while the rest of my application is styled correctly:

```java
    ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                groupData, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childData, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
    ExpandableListView expandableListView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_expandable_list_view);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing in `activity.getApplicationContext()` as the context argument when creating the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`, pass in the `activity` directly. The theme on the application context appears to be wrong:

```java
    ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                activity /* instead of activity.getApplicationContext() */, 
                groupData, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childData, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
```

Though others recommend using a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`/`ExpandableListView`.

Credit to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/d1llj5/listview_in_a_fragment_bad_color_in_dark_theme/ffptulx/) by [u/TheCrazyRed](https://www.reddit.com/user/TheCrazyRed).

Comment: I'm posting this on stackoverflow because I struggled to figure it out and find a solution online. I almost missed the reddit post, and then had to look up what the kotlin double exclamation point meant. Also if someone has more detail on _why_ this happens, please add a comment or edit and I'd be happy to read more and update my post.

Comment: You just made my day!! This fixed my issue perfectly. I didn't use any custom adapter, just creating a new ArrayAdapter and passing my MainActivity.this fixed the problem and my themes now load correctly.